# Showing a subset of sequences is not closed

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

Let $E$  be the set of sequences of real numbers $x = (x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ such that the series
$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{|x_n|}{n^2}$  converges. $E$ is a normed space with $||x||=\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{|x_n|}{n^2}$.

Let $F$ be the set of sequences of real numbers $y = (y_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ such that
$\displaystyle ||y||_∞ = \sup_{n\ge 1}|y_n|$ is finite. Clearly $F \subset E$, and I want to show  that $F$ is not closed in $E$ for $|| · ||$.

My idea is to come up with a sequence of sequences in $F$ such that this sequence of sequences  converge to a sequence in $E$ but this limiting sequence is not in $F$. But I could not find one that makes this true.

Comment: A good first idea in that kind of situation is to take a sequence in $E \,\backslash\, F$, let's call it $u$, and look at the sequences $u^{(k)}$ that are the "truncatures" of $u$: $u^{(k)}_n = u_n$ if $n \leq k$, and $= 0$ if $n > k$. There'll then only be the problem of checking that there's convergence for $(u^{(k)})_k$ to $u$ for $||.\!||$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a natural number $n$, denote by $g^n$ the sequence $g_i^n=\sqrt{n}$ if $i<n$ and $0$ else. We note that $||g^n||_{\infty}<\infty$ and that $g^n$ converges to $(\sqrt{n})_{n}$ in the norm of $E$, yet $(\sqrt{n})_{n}$ does not lie in $F$

Comment: by $(\sqrt{n})_n$ do you mean the sequence of real numbers $v_n=\sqrt {n}$  for all $n\in \mathbb N$ ?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean.